# SSRS REports shrinks in size while printing on zebra printer

Tags: reporting-services

I am facing problem while printing the labels on thermal printer. report output is coming correct in print preview but on printing its shrinks the size .

any suggestions would be highly appreciated 
waiting for feedback

Comment: What is your report size compared to the printer label size? Reset your printer preferences?

Comment: report size is same as printer label size and I cant set the printer preference .Please help on this.